# Rendering a video with webGL in IOS 10 beta 7 (Safari) - shows weird purplish colors

Tags: video, webgl, render, ios10

I'm rendering a video in webGL, by passing a `Video` object as the source for `texImage2D`. 
 This works great in all platforms (that supports webGL), however in Safari in IOS 10 beta 7, it is rendered with weird colors (in previous IOS versions it looks ok).

For example, this is an image frame from it, that looks how it's supposed:
[image]

And this is how it's rendered in IOS 10 (the weird version):

[image]

Is this an IOS10 beta bug?

Here is the render code (that happens for each frame):

```
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);        
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, frameTexture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, video);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
```

`frameTexture` is a 2D texture created before. `video` is a `Video` object.
The vertex buffers have been initialized before to form a rectangle that `holds` the image.

These are the shaders:

**Vertex**

```
attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
    vec4 pos = vec4(a_position, 1.0);
    vec2 xy = vec2(pos.x,pos.y);

    // convert the rectangle from pixels to 0.0 to 1.0
    vec2 zeroToOne = xy / u_resolution;
    // convert from 0->1 to 0->2
    vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;
    // convert from 0->2 to -1->+1 (clipspace)
    vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;
    gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);
    // pass the texCoord to the fragment shader
    // The GPU will interpolate this value between points.
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;        
}
```

`u_resolution` gets the width and height of the video from the JS, before.

**Fragment**

```
precision mediump float;

// our texture
uniform sampler2D u_image;
// the texCoords passed in from the vertex shader.
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord);
}
```

I tried several videos - same result. Though I noticed that whites and blacks looks normal and are rendered ok.

If this is not an IOS10 bug in webGL - any idea what can cause this?
(I should note, that I am not very experienced with webGL)

Comment: Just in case, what are texture's wrap and filter parameters? Have you tried to tinker with them?

Comment: @KirillDmitrenko thanks for the comment. I tried just now. Unfortunately anything other than  `gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE` renders a black rectangle.

Comment: That's right behaviour: setting anything other that `CLAMP_TO_EDGE` for non-power-of-two texture (dimensions aren't powers of two) will make the texture non-renderable, and sampling from such a texture will return just zeroes (in other words, black). Have you tried to different magnification and minification filters? `NEAREST` or `LINEAR`.

Comment: @KirillDmitrenko wrapping and filtering do not affect the actual colors in such a way, the clear answer here is "**yes its a bug**" there is no need to fiddle around with these things. @OP You may try to set `alpha:false` during context creation(`var gl = canvas.getContext({alpha:false})`), or set your textures datatype to `RGB` instead of `RGBA`(usually videos do not have an alpha channel). This is still a bug though and you should report it to apple.

Comment: As to whats going on I suspect that the data extracted from the video by webkit is given to WebGL as BGR data instead of RGB, you could invert that(flip R and B channels in your fragment shader: `gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord).bgra;`) to make it look right again, however as already said its a bug should be fixed by the vendor.

Comment: @LJᛃ You are right :) Reversing it makes it look normal (and purple in all other platforms). I will report this. Appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: @YuvalA. I just ran into this, did you make any progress?

Comment: @Prinzhorn, AFAIK, they haven't fixed it yet. The only solution for now is to swap the rgba order for these versions, like LJ suggested. Perhaps also report it again like I did, so they'll know more people encounter it...

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly a bug in WebKit (or Safari or even iOS itself). A good start would be to report it to WebKit's tracker: https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/.