# Determine RGBA order of OS

Tags: ios, webgl

I am working on a video player which uses webgl. When using the player in a browser on iOS 10.2+ I noticed that the colors are inverted. I added a simple check to determine the iOS version and flip the format accordingly in the shader.

```
    if (u_bgra == 1.0) {
      imageColor = texture2D(u_image, v_image_coordinates).bgra;
    } else {
      imageColor = texture2D(u_image, v_image_coordinates);
    }
```

This is a bit of a hack but works.

Now, with last weeks release of 10.3.3 I noticed that the colors are flipped again. It seems that apple has changed it's internal rgba format again though I don't see any mention in the iOS version history [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history).

Rather than hardcoding a bunch of version numbers is there any way to determine the internal rgba order of the OS on the fly?

Comment: This only happens to video textures doesn't it?

Comment: @LJᛃ Yes, you are right.

Comment: This was/is clearly a bug([see this questions comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39123109/rendering-a-video-with-webgl-in-ios-10-beta-7-safari-shows-weird-purplish-co))... the fact that the fix is not mentioned in the release notes may be an oversight or it may be fixed on accident(f.e. by upgrading webkit itself), either way I'd assume the latter, if you want to be on the safe side(#regression) the only reliable check is to load a video with a single red frame in it, render it then probe it using `glReadPixels` and check if the returned value is red or blue.

Comment: [Related WebKit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=164540) and [Three.js Workaround Discussion](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9754#issuecomment-268197088)

Comment: for future reference you should really just [generate a different shader from JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/greggman/71e081485f2153af2709cc33aaed9ed5) rather than put a branch in your shader.